# What is the purpose of these number signs around date value type?

Tags: sql

Can anyone explain the correct usage/requirement of using these '#' number signs. Do they simply have to surround any date type in SQL?

Thanks

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
OrderDate BETWEEN #07/04/1996# AND #07/09/1996#;
```

Comment: You didn't provide enough info.  Your database engine is relevant as is the application where you saw this code.

Comment: hash tags in MS SQL SERVER denote temp tables, but they wouldn't look like that (wrapping) pretty sure you are not talking SQL Server.

Comment: I got the code from the bottom of this popular SQL tutorial see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp Si I guess it's just SQL?

Answer (score 3):

These are the MS Access syntax for date constants.

In most other databases, you just use a string to represent a date.  In my opinion, you should use one of the ISO standard formats for this (either YYYYMMDD or my preference YYYY-MM-DD).  So a valid date in most databases would be `'2014-01-01'`.  In Access, this can be written `#2014-01-1#`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that is a vendor specific SQL modification. If I am not mistaken, that is specific for MS Access databases that the date should be delimited with a hash.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought so, but the msdn article confused me.

Comment: It came from the bottom of this tutorial page:http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp It's not an ACCESS tutorial though, i thought?

Comment: I think I only used it once in Access. But I'm quite sure I never used it in any other DB.