# Using # to Enclose Date in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, delphi, delphi-2010

I have .mdb Database, with sample data:

```
GameIndx|GameDate           |PlayerID|Duration|Score|
--------|-------------------|--------|--------|-----|
       1|2016-01-11 00:00:00|SM004   |     455| 2200|
       2|2016-01-12 00:00:00|SM004   |     241| 1952|
       3|2016-01-12 00:00:00|SV007   |     381| 1280|
       4|2016-01-12 00:00:00|LK001   |     372| 5237|
```

To run a SELECT to match a certain GameDate:

```
   SQL := 'SELECT GameIndx, GameDate from tblGames where GameDate=#2016/01/11#';
```

This statement works inside of Delphi, and returns the correct column.
To my understanding this is not SQL syntax: Is there any documentation for Delphi regarding the accepted syntax for dates?

```
GameDate=#2016/01/11#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention you're dealing with a .mdb i.e. a Microsoft Access database.  MS Access is unusual amongst SQL databases in that it uses the '#' character as a delimiter for dates, so in this case `GameDate=#2016/01/11#` **IS** in fact valid SQL syntax and is nothing to do with Delphi.

Comment: Thanks you pointed me in the right direction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351259/what-is-the-purpose-of-these-number-signs-around-date-value-type